# WP7 vs Wp8 Session timeout differences

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

When deploying the same XAP file to WP7 and WP8 why would I get different session timeouts? Could this be something client side or all server side?

Comment: Are you using `DispatcherTimer` class?

Answer (score 1):

The session timeouts are always decided by the server and never the client. Irrespective of which client you use the session timeout wouldn't change.